# How pass vector<int> to pthread_create correctly in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I would like to create a thread passing a vector as parameter.
but i got the following errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]

error: initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void* func(void* args)
{
    vector<int>* v = static_cast<vector<int>*>(args);
    cout << "Vector size: " << v->size();
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

  vector<int> integers;
  pthread_t thread;


      for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        integers.push_back(i+1);

       // overheat call
       //pthread_create( &thread, NULL, func, static_cast<void*>(&integers));

       pthread_create( &thread, NULL,func,&integers);

       cout << "Main thread finalized" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

How I can do it properly ?
Thanks

EDIT: forgot the includes posting here only; Revised.

I got new errors:

```
error: stray ‘\305’ in program
error: stray ‘\231’ in program
```

I am trying to know about it.

Thanks in advance.

```
FINAL EDIT : Thanks to all. Sorry, I had another int var called func in other location.
Thanks for your help.
```

Comment: the error is about the 3rd argument, not about the 4th; are you pasting the exact code for reproducing the error? because the compiler doesn't seem to know what 'func' is, so it treats it as an int

Comment: As for the casting... You don't need to cast the vector in the call to `pthread_create`, but in the thread function you must use `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: @stijn Yes, it's the exact code, I am going to cast func. I don`t know why does not recognize the callback.

Comment: @ppk: Are you sure you get those errors from that code? Now you've added `#include <vector>`, GCC [compiles it](http://ideone.com/b3fZ5) with only a warning, due to missing a `return` in `func`. What is your compiler, and are they the only compile errors?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, the includes are right; I am using g++ with codelite under ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @ppk: I see you've just changed the code to cast `func` to `void*`, which is wrong. If you put it back how it was (passing `func` with no cast), then the code should compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have forgotten to include `<vector>`; this confuses the compiler as it first fails to generate `func`, and then fails to identify it as a function in the call to `pthread_create`.

Once you include that, your code should compile (and you can remove the `static_cast<void*>` if you like); but to work correctly you also need to call `pthread_join` before the vector goes out of scope, and return a value from `func`.

UPDATE: your latest edit has broken the code: you should *not* cast `func` to `void*`, but leave it as a function pointer. This should work:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, &integers);
```

Errors like `stray ‘\305’ in program` imply that you have some strange characters in your code, although they're not in the code you've posted. Have a look at the lines that the error messages refer to.